# Get-AzureSubscription -ExtendedDetails in PowerShell doesn't include certificate

Tags: powershell, azure, certificate, vpn, azure-powershell

I'm trying to revoke a VPN certificate using Microsoft's byzantine Azure Powershell commands, as described here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2014/12/09/step-by-step-revoking-and-reinstating-client-vpn-certificates-for-azure-point-to-site-vpns/. (Don't get me started on why you should need to write a 20-line script that makes a manually-constructed REST API call to do basic user management - that's a separate issue for now.)

One of the key bits is getting the appropriate management certificate. You're supposed to use this command:

```
$cert = (Get-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName BizSpark -ExtendedDetails).Certificate
```

One some machines this works. But on my main client machine, the one that I need to run it on, the `Certificate` property is always blank. I've tried re-importing my .publishsettings file, upgrading the Azure Powershell commandlets, deleting the  `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell` directory, and so forth, to no avail.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Ken, when you say on some machines it works, do you mean you are running it locally on a server or you are on your client machine connecting remotely? From your code above, you aren't explicitly hitting an Azure subscription, is it the correct subscription that you are in? From the URL you provided, they explicitly state the subscription name. Looks correct otherwise. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: @TimHaintz - Thanks for the response. See my edited response up above. I'm running `Get-AzureSubscription` on my local machine (which has access to the necessary certificate files) against our default BizSpark subscription. I've worked around the problem for the moment by installing the Azure Powershell tools on a different client machine and running it there, but I still need to figure out how to get it working on my main workstation.

Comment: Thanks @kensmith, sounds like it might be a bug or versioning issue?